# I am unable to pass data from model class to table view in swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

In this I am getting data from server response after posting parameters and here I need to display it on table view and it should be displayed like shown below in the image `0` is the price for the particular shipping method

[image]

already i had written model class for server response data and here it is

```
struct ShippingMethod  {

    let carrierCode : String
    let priceInclTax : Int
    let priceExclTax : Int
    let available : Any
    let carrierTitle : String
    let baseAmount : Int
    let methodTitle : String
    let amount : Int
    let methodCode : String
    let errorMessage : Any


    init(dict : [String:Any]) {

    self.carrierCode = dict["carrier_code"] as! String
    self.priceInclTax = dict["price_incl_tax"]! as! Int
    self.priceExclTax = dict["price_excl_tax"]! as! Int
    self.available = dict["available"]!
    self.carrierTitle = dict["carrier_title"] as! String
    self.baseAmount = dict["base_amount"]! as! Int
    self.methodTitle = dict["method_title"]! as! String
    self.amount = dict["amount"]! as! Int
    self.methodCode = dict["method_code"] as! String
    self.errorMessage = (dict["error_message"] != nil)
  }
}
```

by using this I had formed an array type like this by using code

```
  var finalDict = [String: [String]]()
  var responseData = [ShippingMethod]()
  do
  {
  let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String : Any]]
  for item in array! {
          self.responseData.append(ShippingMethod.init(dict: item))
   }
   print(self.responseData)
   }
   catch let error
   {
       print("json error:", error)
   }
   print(self.responseData)
   for item in self.responseData {
        let dict = item
        let carrierTitle = dict.carrierTitle
        let methodTitle = dict.methodTitle
        if self.finalDict[carrierTitle] == nil {
            self.finalDict[carrierTitle] = [String]()
        }
        self.finalDict[carrierTitle]!.append(methodTitle)
    }
    print(self.finalDict)
```

the output of this `finalDict` is `["Flat Rate": ["Fixed"], "Best Way": ["Table Rate"]]` in this `carrier title` key value pair should be displayed as section title and is `Flat Rate` and `method title` key value pair should be displayed as rows in section `Fixed` but the problem is I need `amount` key value pair with it also for corresponding `method title` can anyone help me how to get this ?

Comment: check my answer here if it might help you understand what needs to be done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885780/issue-with-passing-proper-image-to-tableviewcell/46886205#46886205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create another struct for displaying row data:

```
struct CarrierInfo {
   let name:String
   let amount:Int
}
```

Change your `finalDict`  to

```
var finalDict = [String: [CarrierInfo]]()
```

and create CarrierInfo instance and set it in finalDict

```
for item in self.responseData {
        let dict = item
        let carrierTitle = dict.carrierTitle
        let methodTitle = dict.methodTitle
        let amount = dict.amount
        if self.finalDict[carrierTitle] == nil {
            self.finalDict[carrierTitle] = [CarrierInfo]()
        }
        self.finalDict[carrierTitle]!.append(CarrierInfo(name: carrierTitle, amount: amount))
    }
```

Likewise you can make other required changes. This would neatly wrap your row display data inside a structure.

PS: I have not tested the code in IDE so it may contain typos.

Comment: how to insert the data into this struct ?

Comment: @user0246: Edited the answer. It can give you an idea. You have to make changes in your tableview datasource as well.

Comment: `["Flat Rate": [Ecommerce.CarrierInfo(name: "Fixed", amount: 0), Ecommerce.CarrierInfo(name: "Fixed", amount: 0)], "Best Way": [Ecommerce.CarrierInfo(name: "Table Rate", amount: 0), Ecommerce.CarrierInfo(name: "Table Rate", amount: 0)]]` ur code is working but saving multiple times

Comment: any idea how to avoid

Comment: @user0246: Only you can debug this, check why two instances are getting created inside for loop. Is there duplication of data in  self.responseData or some other mistake. Use breakpoints and debug further.

Comment: `let amount = dict.amount
                if self.finalDict[carrierTitle] == nil {
                    self.finalDict[carrierTitle] = [CarrierInfo.init(name: methodTitle, amount: amount)]
                }
                self.finalDict[carrierTitle]!.append(CarrierInfo.init(name: methodTitle, amount: amount))` I had made changes using ur code but here two times appending data how to avoid this first time appending here `self.finalDict[carrierTitle] = [CarrierInfo.init(name: methodTitle, amount: amount)]`

Comment: and second time is `self.finalDict[carrierTitle]!.append(CarrierInfo.init(name: methodTitle, amount: amount))`

Comment: previously this logic was working fine @Puneet Sharma

Comment: @user0246: Why are you doing this: self.finalDict[carrierTitle] = [CarrierInfo.init(name: methodTitle, amount: amount)] inside if-block. You just need to create empty array of CarrierInfo inside if-block as I have done in the code.

Comment: if I need to get whole count of name that is including all key value pairs

Comment: let count = self.finalDict.reduce(0) {$0+$1.value.count}

Answer (score 0):

You can assign another dictionary with key as `methodTitle` and `amount` as value. i.e., `["fixed":"whatever_amount"]` 
OR 
You can use `finalDict` differently, like `["Flat Rate": ["tilte":"Fixed","amount":"0"], "Best Way": ["title":"Table Rate","amount":"0"]]`

If it is difficult for you to code this, you can revert back.

**Edit**
You can use the following code to create the array in the second solution I suggested above:

```
for item in self.responseData {
    let dict = item
    let carrierTitle = dict.carrierTitle
    let methodTitle = dict.methodTitle
    let amount = dict.amount
    if self.finalDict[carrierTitle] == nil {
        self.finalDict[carrierTitle] = [[String:String]]()
    }
    let innerDict = ["title":methodTitle,"amount":amount]
    self.finalDict[carrierTitle]!.append(innerDict)
}
```

Comment: can u help me how to create this array like as u said ?

Comment: like second method as u said `["Flat Rate": ["tilte":"Fixed","amount":"0"], "Best Way": ["title":"Table Rate","amount":"0"]]`

Comment: because if I need to add more parameters from model class then it is useful for me